# I have a schema in mongoose and i and rendering data from a schema to select the value. But now i also want the id of the selected data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically i have 2 sections. First is category and second is essay. The categories are added in mongoose schema and then the categories are being rendered to add essay in a specific category section. Now when i choose a specific category i also want the id of that category to store in essay schema but cant do so. Any help is appreciated

I have tried mongoose populate and schema.types.object method but aint 
working for me.

// Loading essay model

```
require("../models/essay");
const essay = mongoose.model("essay");
```

// Loading category model

```
require("../models/category");
const category = mongoose.model("category");
```

// Essay processing form

```
router.get("/addessay", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
res.header(
"Cache-Control",
"no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate,max-stale=0, post-check=0, 
pre-check=0"
  );
category.find({}).then(category => {
res.render("addessay", {
category: category
    });
  });
});
```

// Post route to store essay in db

```
router.post("/essay/add", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
res.header(
"Cache-Control",
"no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate,max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
  );
  const newEssay = {
    cat: req.body.category,
    catg: req.body.categoryg,
    body: req.body.body,
    bodygreece: req.body.bodyg
  };

  new essay(newEssay).save().then(essay => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "Essay Succesfully added");
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});
```

//Category Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

// creating the schema

const categorySchema = new Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  categorygreece: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

mongoose.model("category", categorySchema);

//Essay Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

// creating the schema

```
const EssaySchema = new Schema({
  cat: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  catg: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bodygreece: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

mongoose.model("essay", EssaySchema);
```

//Handlebar template (Essay adding form)

```
<main class="page-content my-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
            <h3 class="my-5">Add Your your Essays .!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form action="/essay/add" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select class="categorys form-control mt-4" name="category">
                        {{#each category}}
                        <option value="{{id}}">{{category}}
                        </option>
                        {{/each}}

                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <select class="categorys form-control mt-4" name="categoryg">
                        {{#each category}}
                        <option value="{{id}}">{{categorygreece}}

                        </option>
                        {{/each}}

                    </select>
                </div>




                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="mb-3">Tell us your Essay in English!</h5>
                    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

                    <textarea name="body" id="body-text" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="English Essay"></textarea>

                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace('body');
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="mb-3">Tell us your Essay in Greece!</h5>

                    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

                    <textarea name="bodyg" id="body-text-2" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Greece Essay"></textarea>


                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace('bodyg');
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="form-control btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

So when from options i choose a category i also want the categorys id and have to store that in essay schema.